# How to prevent the character `^[(B` from being displayed on the compilation buffer

Tags: term, characters, compilation-mode, escape

When I run the test feature of Rust in Emacs compilation mode, with [ansi-color](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/ansi-color.el) mode loaded, somehow the character `^[(B` is always displayed like below:

[image]

It looks quite annoying.

Does anyone know how to remove these characters from the compilation buffer?

Comment: Don't put an answer in the question. Post it separately as an answer. If you want, you can accept your own answer, e.g., if it answers your question better or more completely than other answers.

Comment: @Drew: Thanks! I just posted an answer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your shell init files (`~/.bashrc` or similar) are not setting the `TERM` variable to anything. `TERM` will then keep its default value (which is probably `dumb` while `M-x compile` is running things), and your compiler will know that it is not supposed to print any escape sequences. If it still does, file a bug report on the compiler. Or in this case perhaps your test suite.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! Previously, I set `TERM` to `xterm-256color`. Now, I configure it to `(setenv "TERM" "xterm-color")` and the compilation mode works just fine!

Comment: You shouldn’t set it to anything at all. A program that runs other programs (such as Emacs running your compiler) should be free to set it to the appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Using the default dumb shell, the color will not be displayed. I want to see the color too, so I wrote a quick hack only the change the `TERM` variable during the compilation (I updated this part in my question too)

Answer (score 1):

Following @db48x's answer, I wrote a quick function to advise `M-x compile` to use `TERM=xterm-color` during its session.

```lisp
  ;; Advise compile to set TERM variable
  (defun tddsg--advice-compile (func &rest args)
    (let ((saved-term-env (getenv "TERM")))
      ;; Use xterm-color so that the compilation mode can display color properly
      (setenv "TERM" "xterm-color")
      (apply func args)
      (setenv "TERM" saved-term-env)))
  (advice-add 'compile :around #'tddsg--advice-compile)
```

Here is the result:

[image]